# Error no such file or directory in server with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, codeigniter-3

I have a project bulit on framework **Codeigniter** which when uploading it to the server and the attempt to download an *Excel* file with the help of the *PHPExcel* library is signaling me the following error:

> require_once(application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

In local it works to me of the following way, in the folder *libraries*:

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Already tried in the following ways:

```
Way 1:
    require_once "../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
    require_once "../third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
Way 2:
    require_once BASEPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
    require_once BASEPATH."third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
```

But nevertheless I still mark error, like I already gave 777 permissions to all folders thinking that it is error per permissions, but I mark the same error.

The structure of my folders is as follows:

[image]

I would appreciate any comments to solve a problem.

Comment: yes, in the folder phpExcel there are the file phpExcel.php and the folder PHPExcel with the other components of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this : replace `APPPATH."/third_party` with `APPPATH."third_party`

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."third_party/PhpExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once APPPATH."third_party/PhpExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

for more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: make sure `PHPExcel.php` has class name `PHPExcel`

Comment: change ur first folder name from PHPExcel to PhpExcel as in my answer